# launch installer from NFS share

Tags: windows-10, uac, nfs

I'm a domain user in local admins group. I'm trying to launch an installer from a network location, but it tells me that "I don't have a permission for that file" and "suggests Admin assistance" (roughly translated from Russian).

What do I need to do to be able to launch installers by simply clicking on them?

UAC was initially on. I expected a UAC prompt; if I copied the exe locally, the UAC prompt was displayed.

I could also launch EXEs that didn't require admin rights.

Then I set the lowest security in UAC and disabled SmartScreen, but the error didn't go away.

I finally managed to run the installer from an elevated command prompt, but it's not convenient

upd:

It's an NFS share mounted to a drive letter. Setting `EnableLinkedConnections=1` in registry and reboot didn't help - drive letter created by elevated shell is invisible to restricted shell and vice versa. Mapping same drive letter in both shells didn't help either.

I also tried to run the mount command from a scheduled task as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. The drive letter became visible to both shells, but the access denied error didn't go away

Comment: Make sure you have the appropriate permissions to run the file. I am assuming your file server is running some variant of Windows Server. Do you have all the same permissions to the file server as everywhere else on your domain?

Answer (score 0):

Being part of the local admins group (from your local computer) does (most likely) NOT give you permissions to whatever you are accessing via this Network Location. The \Sever\share.. of the installer you are trying to run probably has its own security permissions.

Make sure you a local admin of the server or at least are in a group that the server is aware of that has permission to the installer.

Comment: Now I'm sure the files on server have sufficient permissions set. The problem is is related to how elevation works.